# Empty gridview before user selction?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've set up an .aspx gridview that shows data from an SQL database based on the user selecting the parameter in a drop-down list.

What I'd like to achieve is that the gridview is empty before the user has made a selection. Is this possible?

There will always be data in the database, so the question is NOT about what to display when there are no rows to show.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

//Eva-Lotta

Comment: Why don't you leave the Data Source of the Gridview Empty on Page Load and Select the Data into a Dataset, Set Data Source and DataBind() inside the DropDownList's Selected Index Changed event.

Comment: That sounds logical and feasible - but I was hoping for an easier more "built-in" solution without having to code it myself ... Well, I suppose what my task for the rest of the day will be :)

Comment: ok.. all the best then.

Comment: you can bind Gridview on selectedIndexChange event of dropdown List. Use Dataset to bind the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net 4.0 added the boolean ShowHeaderWhenEmpty property.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**The headers will not appear unless DataBind() is called with something other than null.**

```
GridView1.DataSource = New List(Of String)
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: This suggestion is more for whether or not the headers should be displayed if no data is found, right? If so, it's not applicable for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it in a really simple way! I set gridview visible to false on page load, and true when the user clicked a button. Sometimes it's much easier than expected.